# Monthly rotation call schedule coding done correctly?

Tags: rotation, call, agent

import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import calendar

## Define the start date and end date of the schedule

start_date = pd.Timestamp('2023-05-01')

end_date = pd.Timestamp('2024-04-30')

## Create a list of all the dates in the schedule

date_range = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='D')

## Create a DataFrame to hold the schedule

schedule = pd.DataFrame(index=date_range)

## Create a list of the four employees

employees = ['Employee A', 'Employee B', 'Employee C', 'Employee D']

## Add a column for each employee to the schedule

for employee in employees:

```
schedule[employee] = np.nan
```

## Define a function to assign morning and afternoon shifts to each day

def assign_shifts(date):

```
day_of_week = date.day_name()

if day_of_week in ['Saturday', 'Sunday']:

    return np.nan, np.nan

elif date in calendar.Canada().holidays():

    return np.nan, np.nan

else:

    morning_shift = employees[date.day % len(employees)]

    afternoon_shift = employees[(date.day + 1) % len(employees)]

    return morning_shift, afternoon_shift
```

## Apply the function to each day in the schedule

schedule[['Morning Shift', 'Afternoon Shift']] = schedule.index.map(assign_shifts).apply(pd.Series)

## Export the schedule to an Excel file

schedule.to_excel('monthly_call_schedule.xlsx')

excel table starting May 2023 a monthly call schedule for 4 employees rotating on 2 shifts morning and afternoon in 1 day, no weekends.